# Wrong data inserting in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

Below is my query

```
insert into sms (mobile) values ("255786786072")
```

The value which I am getting in the "mobile" field in table is 2147483647.
data type of "mobile" field is varchar(15).

Any suggestion.

Comment: try to post the result of this statement: `DESC SMS;`.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible.  Are you sure you are looking at the correct database/table/field/record?

Comment: Are you running this in php?  Perhaps your statement is failing and you are just looking at the value for the last record inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm **pretty sure** that it's not `varchar` because `2147483647` is the maximum value of signed `INT`. Change it to varchar to work as desired.